# Get valuable based on Unique DIV ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the requirement getting from CMS. I want to differentiate `#selectTitl`e value based on the different unique `Id` names I am getting.

If I use `#selectTitle.val()`, it picks the first item value only. Not picking the remaining items in the list.

Can please guide me to solve this issue soon?

```js
const val = $('#selectTitle').val();
formData['selected_title'] = val;
```

```html
<div id="id_98912322">
 <select id="selectTitle"><option value="test1" na="false">Test 1</option><option value="test2" na="false">Test 2</option><option value="test3" na="false">Test 3</option></select>
</div>

<div id="id_78112121">
 <select id="selectTitle"><option value="test1" na="false">Test 1</option><option value="test2" na="false">Test 2</option><option value="test3" na="false">Test 3</option></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `id` must be unique. But in this case you don't need id. You need class because you have some select box and need all value of them to send as form data.

So add same class (say `selectTitle`) to select box and then get value of the class by:

```
$('.selectTitle').map((_,el) => el.value).get();
```

```js
function getAllValue(){
   const vals = $('.selectTitle').map((_,el) => el.value).get();
   console.log(vals)
  //formData['selected_title'] = val;
}

getAllValue();
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="id_98912322">
 <select id="selectTitle1" class="selectTitle"><option value="test1" na="false">Test 1</option><option value="test2" na="false">Test 2</option><option value="test3" na="false">Test 3</option></select>
</div>

<div id="id_78112121">
 <select id="selectTitle1" class="selectTitle"><option value="test1" na="false">Test 1</option><option value="test2" na="false">Test 2</option><option value="test3" na="false">Test 3</option></select>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="getAllValue()">Get all value </button>
```

Comment: Thanks Alireza. Just now i did myself similar method to solve this issue.